# Why transmission insulators have a particular shape?

Tags: creepage, insulator

What I have gathered is that to increase the creepage distance (the shortest distance along the surface of solid insulating material between two conductive parts) they have designed a particular shape. But how does large creepage distance help in avoiding the flashover? And in the rain how can it avoid the flashover because continuous droplets of water can short circuit the live conductor to ground.

Comment: Have you measured the conductance of rain water? How would it form a continuous path on the ribs of the insulator?

Comment: In the case of heavy rain, it might be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct! What is normally ignored in looking at this solution is the surface contamination from the atmosphere. If the insulators are not cleaned flash over will eventually occur ambient conditions dependent. There is a process where they are cleaned with water while still powered. You can use "cleaning transmission line insulators" as a search term to learn more. It is my understanding that is one of the reasons power lines need access.

Comment: But going to each and every insulator and cleaning it up is a very cumbersome process. there must be an alternative.

Comment: And why do they have a shiny and smooth surface?

Comment: It is time consuming and cumbersome process, there is a lot of automation in that area. I have seen it done with helicopters. They need to be non porous so it stays smooth which is shiney because of the material. The base (center) is from what I have seen is fiberglass  with porcelain "rings" as outer layer. Follow the link: "cleaning transmission line insulators" and yes they use water even on the 500,000 volt lines.